# In algpseudocode, \algrenewcommand doesn't work for \algorithmicelsif

Tags: algorithmicx, algpseudocode

I would like to customize keywords in `algpseudocode`, including the rendering of `\ElsIf`. But when I compile the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicthen{\relax}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{If}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{Else}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelsif{Elif}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get a syntactic error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \ALG@cmd@2@algorithmicelsif undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.7 \algrenewcommand\algorithmicelsif
                                     {Elif}
?
```

whereas the first three `algrenewcommand`s work fine.  What am I doing wrong?

I can see that the style file `algorithmic.sty` contains

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{if}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{then}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelse}{\textbf{else}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelsif}{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif}
```

and so I thought that it should be possible to redefine any of these commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`algorithmic.sty` forms part of the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), while [`algpseudocode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty) forms part of the [`algorithmicx` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), so you're comparing code that isn't used at all. The latter defines `\ElsIf` to use `\algorithmicelse` and `\algorithmicif`, so redefining those should suffice. Alternatively, if you want a different output via `\ElsIf`, define it as such:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algrenewcommand\algorithmicthen{\relax}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{If}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{Else}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{End}

\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{ElsIf}[1]{ElIf\ #1}% Update display of \ElsIf

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \If{$quality \geq 9$}
    \State $a \gets perfect$
  \ElsIf{$quality \geq 7$}
    \State $a \gets good$
  \ElsIf{$quality\geq 5$}
    \State $a \gets medium$
  \ElsIf{$quality \geq 3$}
    \State $a \gets bad$
  \Else
    \State $a \gets unusable$
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

The above example code was partially taken from the [`algorithmicx` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithmicx).

Answer (score 1):

The package code (`algpseudocode.sty`) has

```
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{ElsIf}[1]{\algorithmicelse\ w\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}%
```

so `ElseIf` is defined in terms of `\algorithmicelse` and `\algorithmicthen` there is not, by default any command  `\algorithmicelsif`

The package is based on `algorithmicx.sty` not the `algorithmic.sty` that you showed a fragment of.

Comment: Probably this means that I should use `algorithmic` instead of `algorithmicx`.  I do not want `\ElsIf` to consist of `else` and `if` (find it confusing) and would like to have the Python-style `elif`.

Comment: @Vlad: You can update `\ElsIf` to display however you want. See [my updated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623732/5764).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot.